# Greasemonkey delay... setTimeout doesnt work ok

Tags: javascript, loops, greasemonkey, settimeout

I've been playing around with a site, in which I want to continue clicking a button for `i` amount of times every `interval` seconds.

My code is:

```
clickbidBtn1 = function() {
    var bidBtn=document.getElementById("BidButton");

    var interval = 15000;
    for (var i=3; i>=0; i--){
    setTimeout(bidBtn.click(1);,i*interval);
};
```

I've found out that GM executes all `i` amount of clicks at the same time, not with the intended delay. is there a way to delay the time of click? Say i wanted the function to click the button every 15 second for `i` amount of times.

I was thinking of giving it some more variables, and adding one variable in the `settimeout` code part, which only executes @ the click, then comparing increased variables with current ones before going to the next `settimeout`... but haven't thought it through yet... it seems to be a complicated process for a simple process... :(  i wll play around with it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) for this.

One way:

```
var bidClickTimer       = 0;
var numBidClicks        = 0;

function clickbidBtn1 ()
{
    var interval        = 15000;
    bidClickTimer       = setInterval (function() {BidClick (); }, interval);
}

function BidClick ()
{
    numBidClicks++;
    if (numBidClicks > 3)
    {
        clearInterval (bidClickTimer);
        bidClickTimer   = "";
    }
    else
    {
        bidBtn.click (1);
    }
}

clickbidBtn1 ();
```

---

Alternatively, without using global vars:

```
function clickbidBtn1 ()
{
    var interval            = 15000;
    this.numBidClicks       = 0;
    this.bidClickTimer      = 0;
    this.BidClick           = function () {
                                numBidClicks++;
                                if (numBidClicks > 3)
                                {
                                    clearInterval (bidClickTimer);
                                    bidClickTimer   = "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    bidBtn.click (1);
                                }
                            };
    this.bidClickTimer      = setInterval (function(thisScope) {thisScope.BidClick (); }, interval, this);
}

clickbidBtn1 ();
```

Comment: @ brock. thanks, but for some reason i still get the same result. all 3 clicks go @ the same time, with no delay, not even for the fist one.  sory my mistake...:) saved the script as the wrong format and didnt install the right one:P its working.

Comment: @ Brock, another small thing concerning this question...if i need it to count down the interval or 15seconds first before clicking, how do i go ahead? currently its clicking first then counting before the next click.

Comment: @Ludwig, the code in this answer *does* wait 15 seconds before the first click.  If you have code that is behaving differently, post it in another question and we'll see what's different.

Comment: @ brock. Sorry, didnt hav my thinking cap on last night:) was tired after work and didnt see my mistakes. All is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain why your code does not work: You are **calling** the `.click` method **immediately** (putting `()` after a function name calls the function) and actually passing the **return value** of that function to `setTimeout`. The `for` loop is so fast that everything seem to happen at the same time.

You have to **pass a function reference** to `setTimeout`, e.g. an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    bidBtn.click(1);
}, i*interval);
```

Comment: oh ok, good to know. had me bzy trying a few differnt ways the past 2 hours, but the result stayed the same. but Broc's code helped, as he have been an great help the past day or 2.